# What is the questionmark ? (NOT USED WITH :) in Java means

Tags: java, rtti

I saw a block of code:

```
public abstract List<Class<? extends Pet>> types();
```

(before which shows that Class Dog and Cat are inherited from the Class Pet)
What does the question mark ? means here?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called a wildcard, useful when defining generic types. Take a look at this example from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

```
Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add(new Object()); // Compile time error
```

> Since we don't know what the element type of c stands for, we cannot add objects to it. The add() method takes arguments of type E, the element type of the collection. When the actual type parameter is ?, it stands for some unknown type. Any parameter we pass to add would have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don't know what type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is null, which is a member of every type.

Also from the great Java Generics [FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#Wildcards):

> A wildcard describes a family of types.  There are 3 different flavors of wildcards:

- " ? " - the unbounded wildcard. It stands for the family of all types.
- " ? extends Type " - a wildcard with an upper bound. It stands for the family of all types that are subtypes of Type , type Type being included.
- " ? super Type " - a wildcard with a lower bound. It stands for the family of all types that are supertypes of Type , type Type being included.

> Wildcards are used to declare so-called wildcard parameterized types, where a wildcard is used as an argument for instantiation of generic types. Wildcards are useful in situations where no or only partial knowledge about the type argument of a parameterized type is required.

Answer (score 0):

? Is a wild card suggesting "anything". In ur example it means list of all classes which extend Pet. Could be Dog or Cat or any animal which is a Pet